# Only Keep Certain Combinations of Predictors in a Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

Imagine that I have a data frame like this:

```
> col1 <- rep(1:3,10)
> col2 <- rep(c("a","b"),15)
> col3 <- rnorm(30,10,2)
> sample_df <- data.frame(col1 = col1, col2 = col2, col3 = col3)
> head(sample_df)
  col1 col2      col3
1    1    a 13.460322
2    2    b  3.404398
3    3    a  8.952066
4    1    b 11.148271
5    2    a  9.808366
6    3    b  9.832299
```

I only want to keep combinations of predictors which, together, have a col3 standard deviation below 2. I can find the combinations using ddply, but I don't know how to backtrack to the original DF and select the correct levels.

```
> sample_df_summ <- ddply(sample_df, .(col1, col2), summarize, sd = sd(col3), count = length(col3))
> head(sample_df_summ)
  col1 col2       sd count
1    1    a 2.702328     5
2    1    b 1.032371     5
3    2    a 2.134151     5
4    2    b 3.348726     5
5    3    a 2.444884     5
6    3    b 1.409477     5
```

For clarity, in this example, I'd like the DF with col1 = 3, col2 = b and col1 = 1 and col 2 = b. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "keep" column that is TRUE only if the standard deviation is below 2. Then, you can use a left join (merge) to add the "keep" column to the initial dataframe. In the end, you just select with keep equal to TRUE.

```
# add the keep column
sample_df_summ$keep <- sample_df_summ$sd < 2
sample_df_summ$sd <- NULL
sample_df_summ$count <- NULL

# join and select the rows
sample_df_keep <- merge(sample_df, sample_df_summ, by = c("col1", "col2"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
sample_df_keep <- sample_df_keep[sample_df_keep$keep, ]
sample_df_keep$keep <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
sample_df %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% mutate(sd = sd(col3)) %>% filter(sd < 2)
```

You get:

```
#Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
#Groups: col1, col2
# 
#  col1 col2      col3        sd
#1    1    a 10.516437 1.4984853
#2    1    b 11.124843 0.8652206
#3    2    a  7.585740 1.8781241
#4    3    b  9.806124 1.6644076
#5    1    a  7.381209 1.4984853
#6    1    b  9.033093 0.8652206
```

Comment: This is not quite what I want. I would like the original data frame, but only with combinations of predictors where the standard deviation of the col3 values for that combination is less than 2.

Comment: @goldisfine Something like this: `sample_df %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% mutate(sd = sd(col3)) %>% filter(sd < 2)` ? That way you keep the original df, append a column with `sd(col3)` and filter the df with `sd < 2`

Comment: Yes, that seems more like the right idea and a better answer.

Comment: @goldisfine Edited the answer accordingly